# Log formatting in Grafana explorer

Tags: logging, grafana

I see logs like this in grafana, where each line is a json and in that json there is a field log which contains actual spring boot logs,

```
{"time":"2024-02-14T15:07:44.646998525Z","stream":"stdout","_p":"F","log":"\t... 88 common frames omitted","kubernetes":{"pod_id":"ff01dde1-a3ee-44ec-87e4-d08b7ad7cb2e","labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"common-cis-fraud-detection","app.kubernetes.io/name":"cis-fraud-detection","app.kubernetes.io/part-of":"common"},"annotations":{"common-platform.com/logs":"enabled","kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt":"2024-02-14T08:50:14+01:00","prometheus.io/path":"/actuator/prometheus","prometheus.io/port":"8501","prometheus.io/scrape":"true"}

{"time":"2024-02-14T15:07:44.646996072Z","stream":"stdout","_p":"F","log":"\tat org.jose4j.jwk.HttpsJwks.getJsonWebKeys(HttpsJwks.java:161)","kubernetes":{"pod_id":"ff01dde1-a3ee-44ec-87e4-d08b7ad7cb2e","labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"common-cis-fraud-detection","app.kubernetes.io/name":"cis-fraud-detection","app.kubernetes.io/part-of":"common"},"annotations":{"common-platform.com/logs":"enabled","kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt":"2024-02-14T08:50:14+01:00","prometheus.io/path":"/actuator/prometheus","prometheus.io/port":"8501","prometheus.io/scrape":"true"}

{"time":"2024-02-14T15:07:44.646994795Z","stream":"stdout","_p":"F","log":"\tat org.jose4j.jwk.HttpsJwks.refresh(HttpsJwks.java:204)","kubernetes":{"pod_id":"ff01dde1-a3ee-44ec-87e4-d08b7ad7cb2e","labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"common-cis-fraud-detection","app.kubernetes.io/name":"cis-fraud-detection","app.kubernetes.io/part-of":"common"},"annotations":{"common-platform.com/logs":"enabled","kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt":"2024-02-14T08:50:14+01:00","prometheus.io/path":"/actuator/prometheus","prometheus.io/port":"8501","prometheus.io/scrape":"true"}
```

and I want to format it to see only value of "log" keys in these json, but not able to understand how to parse it in grafana logs explorer

Comment: Where are logs actually stored? In Loki or something else? Please edit in information about data source and your current query.

Comment: It's in prometheus

Comment: You store logs in Prometheus? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add json formatter, and then you can filter out fields:

[image: Grafana json formatter]

Press operations -> Formats -> Json. If you have any non-json lines, add "No pipeline errors" operation to filter them out

Answer (score 0):

I had to do :

```
{app_kubernetes_io_instance="common-cis-fraud-detection", environment="pro"} | json | line_format `{{.log}}`
```